# Calculating download time in an asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I am trying to calculate time taken to download a file as part of a monitoring app. The way I am currently giong about doing this in the Download button click event is as follows

1. Take the time before the Download operation takes place
2. Complete Download operation using WebClient and HTTPResponse
3. Take the time and update it on the page.

The problem is that after step2, there is no updates on the label on the page where I am updating the statistic, because either there is no post back or the control goes off the page. This is the code snippet from my program.

```
        //Taking time stamp before download
        TimeSpan sdt = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

        //Downlaod operation
        System.Net.WebClient req=new System.Net.WebClient();
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + filePath);
        byte[] data=req.DownloadData(filePath);
        response.BinaryWrite(data);

        //Getting end time
        TimeSpan edt= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        TimeSpan dd = endDownloadTime - startDownloadTime;

        //Setting The lable
        DownloadDuration.Text = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", dd.Hours, downloadDuration.Minutes, downloadDuration.Seconds, downloadDuration.Milliseconds);
```

With the above code, the download takes place but the label doesn't get updated as there is no post back. So , I even tried placing the Download button and the label in an update panel. But then, the download button just doesn't work. Can anyone let me know any cleaner way of getting the download latency? or how to go about with the above solution?

Comment: when you used that in the update panel did you set your button to asyncpostback trigger ?

Comment: Yes I did. But then, the button performs only the action on the label on the UpdatePanel. It is not performing the download action. I also tried placing both the button and the label in the updatepanel which doesn't work either.

Comment: can you try client side to see if it works ? like use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "changeLabel", "ChangeLabel();" false);` then on change label set your time in a javascript on your page.